# Доступ к textarea другого html-файла

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

У меня есть два html-файла. В первом содержатся чекбоксы, при выборе которых формируется текст. Во втором есть textarea, в котором этот текст должен выводиться. Как получить доступ к textarea?

Comment: GET/POST запрос с параметрами на вашу вторую страницу

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Есть "адекватный" вариант - это создать контроллер, к примеру с помощью `ASP.NET` либо другого средства или языка. И как говорили в комментарии отправлять на него GET либо POST запрос, и формировать вторую страницу с теми данными которые вы передали запросом.

Либо "костыльный" вариант - после выбора на первой странице один их пунктов:

1. Сохранить вариант выбора как вариант в куках.
2. Перенаправить на вторую страницу.
3. Вытащить из куков все нужные данные и отобразить их на странице.

(Этот вариант я привел тк. я понимаю вам нужна реализация только html + js)

Comment: Извиняюсь за поздний ответ. Спасибо, попробую вариант с костылем.